# Complement method?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 8 letters H,H,C,W,A,O,N,G.
I would like to find out the number of ways to arrange them in a row such that the letters H,C,W are together in one unit.

Using the slotting method, we have $4080$ as the answer. It is obtained by $$4!\times^5C_1\times10+4!\times^5C_2\times2\times3!=4080$$

For $4!\times^5C_1\times10$, $4!$ means arrange A,O,N,G in a row, $^5C_1$ means five x as seen in xAxOxNxGx choose 1 for the (H,C,W,H) to reside, $10$ means the cases HHCW, HHWC,HCHW,HWHC,HCWH,HWCH,CHWH,WHCH,CWHH,WCHH.

For $4!\times^5C_2\times2\times3!$, $4!$ means arrange A,O,N,G in a row, $^5C_2$ means five x as seen in xAxOxNxGx choose 2 for the (H,C,W),(H) to reside, $3!$ means arrange H,C,W among themselves, and $2$ means for the two x's chosen earlier, either we have (H,C,W),(H) into the two arrows or (H),(H,C,W) into the two arrows.

What I am curious is, and am stuck, the method to obtain $A$ in the following: $$6!\times3!-A=4080$$

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem.  The computation that I have for the original problem is $~6! \times 3! = 4320,~$ which does not agree with your computation of $~2880.$  My approach was to consider "HCW" to be one fused unit, that can be internally permuted in $~3!~$ ways.  Then, instead of $~8~$ units to permute, you have $~6~$ units to permute, which can be done in $~6!~$ ways.  Perhaps I have misinterpreted the problem.  In any event, before I can review your posting, I need you to very carefully explain how you are interpreting the problem.  ...see next comment

Comment: Then, I need you to explain, in very careful detail, exactly what led you to the computation of $$4!\times^5C_1\times\frac{4!}{2!}+4!\times^5C_2\times3!=2880.$$  Finally, unless I am overlooking something, I need you to explain what your variable $~A~$ is supposed to represent, and why you are trying to compute the value of $~A.~$  Alternatively, if some other reviewer understands your intent, perhaps they will *step up*.  If you are interested in my attacking the question, then after you edit your posting, leave a comment addressed to me (i.e. it needs to include @user2661923).

Comment: Yes. I think I made a mistake. Let me update my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you count $6! \times 3!$, you count twice all configurations with a subset in {HCWH,HWCH}

So the answer is : $6! \times 3! -2 \times 5! = 4080$

But I need to be honest, I know that the duplicates are $240$, so I search an explanation compatible with this $240$. The logic method to raise to $4080$ is your first method.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I think I just solved it. $A=5\times2\times4!$, where $2$ means the duplicates, for example, (H),(C,W,H) and (H,C,W),(H), $5$ means the 5 X's earlier choose 1 for (H),(C,W,H) to reside, and 4! means arrange A,O,N,G in a row.